# FragmentStatePagerAdapter performance issue with unknown number of fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

For so long I have been searching a reliable answer to my performance issue. But couldn't find and answer yet, as far as I saw everyone has confused about it.

Basically, I have a list of news (that are shown in listview as headlines) in one activity and details of a single news object in my detail activity. I have changed the detail activity to hold a viewpager that extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I usually have 20/25 news in my main headline activity.

As user clicks on a single listview item it passes the list of news to next activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Detail.class);
bundle.putInt("pos", i);
intent.putExtra("news", newsList);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

My detail activity gets the bundled data from headline activity and prepares the adapter:

```
fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
news = (ArrayList) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("news");
current = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos");
fragments2 = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);

adapterViewPager = new ViewFlipperAdapter(current, getApplicationContext(), fm, news, handler, version());
vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
vpPager.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

vpPager.setCurrentItem(current);
vpPager.setOnPageChangeListener(Detail.this);
```

My adapter for the viewpager:

```
public class ViewFlipperAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<News> news;
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean version;
    private Context context;
    private int current;

    public ViewFlipperAdapter(int current, Context context, FragmentManager fm, List<News> news,
                              Handler handler, boolean version) {
        super(fm);
        this.news = news;
        this.handler = handler;
        this.version = version;
        this.context = context;
        this.current = current;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return DetailFragment.newInstance(current, context, news.get(position), handler, version);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.news.size();
    }
}
```

And finally my fragment:

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public DetailFragment() {
    }

    //view initialization
    boolean version;
    String detailTitle;
    String detailSpot;
    String detailImage;
    String detailText;
    String video;
    String url;
    //get holder
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    // newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
    public static DetailFragment newInstance(int current, Context c, News n, Handler h, boolean version) {
        DetailFragment fragmentFirst = new DetailFragment();
        handler = h;
        cont = c;
        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //initalise everything related to a news object inside bundle.
        args.putString(Statics.detailTitle, n.getTitle());
        args.putString(Statics.detailSpot, n.getSpot());
        args.putString(Statics.detail_image_inner, n.getImage());
        args.putString(Statics.playButton, n.getVideo());
        args.putString(Statics.detailText, n.getText());
        args.putString(Statics.category_detail, n.getCategory());
        args.putString(Statics.button_fb, n.getWeb());
        args.putBoolean(Statics.version, version);
        args.putInt(Statics.current, current);
        fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentFirst;
    }
// Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);

        //adview related.
        containerWidth = cont.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        ((WindowManager) cont.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        containerWidth = cont.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        width = dm.widthPixels;


        holder.detailTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
        holder.detailSpot = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailSpot);
        holder.detailText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailText);
        holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        holder.detailImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailImageInner);
        holder.detailImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        holder.playImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        holder.progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        holder.shareButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonFB);
        holder.playImage.setOnClickListener(this);

        //some setters for image and textviews...

        return view;
    }
```

The problem is, as I click on a single list item, it shows the detail of a single news item. Until here I don't see anything wrong. But when I swipe between views the app is getting really slow to process views again and again. Moreover the page I jumped from doesn't stay with the data I have set. (Swiping back to previous view causes a re-loading of view.)

How can I overcome this? (By the way I am using fedorvlasov's lazy loading lib and dfp sdk, they are initialized for each view individually.)

-PS. I have tried ViewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit() but it doesn't seem efficient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you disabling the HW acceleration?

Comment: ok then,  I will remove it and give it a try.

Comment: Still the performance problem occurs.

Comment: Did you find an answer buddy?

Comment: No I could not. Do you have the answer?